# Finding the limit as h goes to zero

Tags: limits

It seems to be a simple question, but I couldn't figure it out.

I want to find

$$\lim_{h\to 0}  \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt {x+h}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt {x}}}{h}$$

I don't know how to control the font size.

Comment: This is the definition of derivative of $f(x)=\frac 1{\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: Try multiplying top and bottom by $\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x + h}$ for a more familiar form. Then, multiply by the conjugate to finish it.

Comment: @polfosol Yes. I want to simplify this..

Comment: Duplicate: [Find the derivative of the function $f(x)=\frac 1{\sqrt{x}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/202347/201168). (*Found using [Approach0.xyz](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bh%5Cto0%7D%5Cfrac%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7Bx%2Bh%7D%7D%20-%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%20%7Bx%7D%7D%7D%7Bh%7D%24&p=1)*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}{h} & =\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x+h}}{h\sqrt{x(x+h)}}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x+h})(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+h})}{h\sqrt{x(x+h)}(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+h})} \\
& =\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x-(x+h)}{h\sqrt{x(x+h)}(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+h})}=-\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h}{h\sqrt{x(x+h)}(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+h})}\\
&=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x}}=-\frac{1}{2x^{3/2}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

observe that $$\frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x+h}}{h\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+h}}=\frac{x-x-h}{h\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+h}(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+h}}$$